# Bootstrap Navbar and Position Logo on Right Side of Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

Struggling a bit with some CSS navbar layouts and positioning the logo in the right hand side of the navbar.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0g9w8zza/3/).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navbar-offcanvas" data-canvas="body">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand pull-right" href="#">
                    <img src="http://assets.inhabitat.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2010/05/BP-Redesign-Contest-4-75x75.jpg" alt="Alternate Text for Image" >
                </a>

                <div class="navbar-offcanvas offcanvas navmenu-fixed-left">
                    <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">eServices</a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Menu 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Menu 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Menu 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Menu 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

1. Notice that the logo is positioned improperly.
2. When you hover over Menu 4, the effect is that the logo gets covered with the hover effect.

What I want to accomplish is something similar to this:

[image]
Notice that the logo is outside the navigation menu item, so that when I hover over the menu, the logo doesn't get covered.

Also, I need the logo to be positioned, right beside the collapsed navigation bar (as shown below) when the page is being viewed in mobile devices.

[image]

What proper css (or html tags) do I need to set to get this? Totally struggling with this for quite some time already.

Thanks.

Update: The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0g9w8zza/3/embedded/result/) must be viewed on Chrome (not sure why FF does not justify the nav items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that I got the effect that you were going for. http://jsfiddle.net/0g9w8zza/4/. The following was added:

```
.nav {
    padding-right: 75px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    right: 75px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Two things were added:

- The hover state problem was happening because the menu *technically* extended all the way to the right side. Adding padding-right gives the logo white space in which to live (with your existing `position: absolute; right: 0`.).
- The .navbar-toggle was also there, but hidden behind the image. `position: absolute; right: 75px;` puts it in the right place.

**Note:** Both classes assume your logo will always be 75 pixels. Alternate scenarios:

- If you are using a CSS Pre-Processor like Less or Sass, use a variable here to make changes easier.
- If you are using a fluid logo width, you can use percentages. I demonstrate this here: http://jsfiddle.net/0g9w8zza/6/. (In the Fiddle, logo width is 20%, and it still works; scale the Run window up and down to check).

(Let me know if this doesn't address your question, and I'd be happy to revisit).

Comment: You're a lifesaver! By the way, if I want to add a text line right below the navbar, would you be able to add it as well?